# python scapy dns sniff

Tags: python, python-3.x, сеть, scapy

есть задача, сделать на python scapy мониторинг dns запросов на локальной машине.
Что бы просто записывать в файл домены сайтов куда обращалась локальная машина.
В интернете не нашел такого, там все про атаки и подмены пакетов, а мне нужно просто мониторить куда обращается машина.

Т.е. если я локально запускаю этот скрипт и через браузер захожу в google, то в файле должно появится time - google.ru

Comment: Думаю, что с помощью одного только scapy такое сделать не получиться. Для примера, вы можете с помощью scapy перехватить http трафик и соответственно, получить оттуда адрес. А вот https уже будет зашифрован. И тут нужно будет воспользоваться сторонними инструментами, такими, как, например: sslstrip.

Comment: То есть, вам нужно перенаправить порты, чтобы весь трафик проходил через sslstrip, и уже только потом выполнять перехват. Когда sslstrip уберет шифрование. Но вот только такое прокатывает не со всеми сайтами. И с тем же Google, к примеру, не получиться. В общем, это сложный вопрос. Не сказать, что нерешаемый. Но для того, чтобы просто сохранять ссылки вам нужно постараться.

Comment: @Евгений а для чего использовать sslstrip и http трафик, если dns по 53 порту вроде идет в открытом виде, не считая doh. scapy вроде умеет dns хватать

Comment: В принципе да, вы правы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изначально нужно установить scapy командой:
pip install --pre scapy[basic]
А затем, можно попробовать так:

```
import subprocess

from scapy.all import sniff


def ip_iface():
    com_run = subprocess.check_output('ip -h -br a | grep UP', shell=True).decode()
    default_interface = com_run.split()[0].strip()
    local_ipv4 = com_run.split()[2].strip().split("/")[0]
    local_ipv6 = com_run.split()[3].strip().split("/")[0]
    return default_interface, local_ipv4, local_ipv6


def packet_sniff(packet):
    qname = packet['DNS Question Record'].qname.decode()
    print(f'Запрос: {qname[0:-1]}')


def main():
    from os import getuid
    if not getuid() == 0:
        print('\n[+] Запустите скрипт с правами суперпользователя!\n')
        return
    print(f'[+] Анализ пакетов... \n')
    sniff(iface=ip_iface()[0], filter='dst port 53', count=0, store=False, prn=packet_sniff)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

у меня Linux, потому скрипт писал под него. Но, если у вас Windows, скрипт будет работать и под ним. Нужно просто из main() удалить все, оставить только sniff.

Из sniff удалить iface, так как это фильтр, который фильтрует запросы только к активной сетевой карте. Ну и соответственно, уберите функцию ip_iface().

В Linux скрипт нужно запускать с повышенными правами, то есть от суперпользователя, так как scapy работает с повышенными правами. А под Windows, если не ошибаюсь, запускать от имени администратора не обязательно. Единственное, что под Windows нужно будет для scapy, чтобы он работал, установить [Npcap](https://npcap.com/#download), в дополнение к scapy.

Ну и скрипт, с учетом всего удаленного будет выглядеть так:

```
from scapy.all import sniff


def packet_sniff(packet):
    qname = packet['DNS Question Record'].qname.decode()
    print(f'Запрос: {qname[0:-1]}')


def main():
    sniff(filter='dst port 53', count=0, store=False, prn=packet_sniff)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Я тут немного "поиздевался" над скриптом )). В итоге получилось примерно это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: отличное рабочее решение спасибо большое!

Comment: А как получить адрес dns? например 8.8.8.8 или 77.88.8.8 чтобы знать у кого запрашивается?
а то по dst идет адрес ближайшего коммутатора...

А Вы получили IP домена сразу из пакета или повторным обращением к домену?

Comment: Пакет состоит из нескольких уровней, которые состоят из протоколов. То есть Ethernet, TCP, IP, DNS. И уже в DNS тот уровень, где я беру адрес. Если вы напишете вместо qname = packet['DNS Question Record'].qname.decode() - qname = packet.show(), вы все эти уровни увидите. А адрес, если он передается, можно взять чуть глубже, packet['DNS Resource Record'].rdata.decode(). Но ip там есть не всегда. Потому я просто забираю из полученного адреса домен и делаю запрос вроде такого: socket.gethostbyname(domen). Примерно так.