# Перехват открытых ссылок в браузере

Tags: python, requests

По фану делаю антивирус на питоне, сейчас хочу сделать отслеживание вредоносных сайтов. Для этого мне потребуется как то перехватывать открытые ссылки в браузерах. Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1443819/python-scapy-dns-sniff/1443979#1443979.), совсем недавно, я отвечал на похожий вопрос

То есть, вам нужно организовать перехват пакетов. Но ограничиваться DNS, если вы хотите сделать что-то вроде антивируса не стоит. Следует перехватывать все dst на всех портах, которые проходят через сетевую карту.